# Open visualforce page in a browser via sforce.one.navigateURL()

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am working on integrating third party application with Salesforce. As part of a use case, I am looking for opening a visualforce page using anchor tag in a browser from an Android mobile app - salesforce1. It works fine when I try to do that using window.open() function. But when I hit that anchor tag, salesforce1 app gives me an option to open the link using Salesforce1 or my default browser. Is there a workaround to avoid this, as I want the visualforce page to be opened using browser without providing the user with that option at all.

Also, is it possible to open a visualforce page in a browser using sforce.one.navigateToURL() function?

Comment: this may help you: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000206264&type=1

Answer (score 0):

you can open  visualforce page using  sforce.one.navigateToURL() function using below format : -

```
sforce.one.navigateToURL('/apex/OppClosureDeclaration?testvariable ='+records1[0].Id);
```

think it helps.

Comment: In this case, is OppClosureDeclaration your visualforce page? This would still open within Salesforce1. I want my visualforce page to open up in browser window when I hit a link from Salesforce1.